# How to run odoo in https mode using nginx?

Tags: nginx, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to run odoo in https mode using nginx but its not working. This is how I tried,

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:odoo -out server.temp.key 2048
sudo openssl req -new -passin pass:odoo -key server.temp.key -out server.csr
sudo openssl rsa -in server.temp.key -out server.key
sudo rm server.temp.key
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

my certificate file,

```
 upstream odoo {
    server localhost:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=3000s;
 }

 server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;
    server_name odoo.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_ciphers                 ALL:!ADH:!MD5:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    # Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
    # as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
    client_max_body_size        200m;

    # add ssl specific settings
    keepalive_timeout           60;

    # increase proxy buffer to handle some OpenERP web requests
    proxy_buffers               16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size           128k;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://odoo;

        # Force timeouts if the backend dies
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

        # Set headers
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # Let the Odoo web service know that we're using HTTPS, otherwise
        # it will generate URL using http:// and not https://
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # Set timeouts
        proxy_connect_timeout   3600;
        proxy_send_timeout      3600;
        proxy_read_timeout      3600;
        send_timeout            3600;

        # By default, do not forward anything
        proxy_redirect          off;
    }

    # Cache some static data in memory for 60mins.
    # under heavy load this should relieve stress on the Odoo web interface a bit.
    location ~* /[0-9a-zA-Z_]*/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid       200 60m;
        proxy_buffering         on;
        expires                 864000;
        proxy_pass              http://odoo;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo-ssl.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/odoo-ssl.error.log;

}
```

After this I restarted nginx,enabled proxy mode in odoo config and restarted odoo server, but still my site runs in http mode. I have not given any domain name to my site. Is that compulsory before setting up nginx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's start from the beginning. In order to have set Odoo with ssl you need:

1) domain name

2) proper config for reverse proxy(you are using nginx so it will be easy fix)

3) ssl certificate

4) updated Odoo config

**I have wrote down some hints to the above points**

1) I assume that you have a domain pointing to your server. If not then you need to visit your domain control panel and set dns(simply put your server IP in "A" value). Sample tutorial on this(see point 5):
https://www.cier.tech/blog/blog-1/post/how-to-publish-your-website-on-amazon-ec2-linux-ubuntu-server-13

2) Sample Odoo config:

```
 upstream odoo {
     server 127.0.0.1:8069;
    }
    upstream odoochat {
     server 127.0.0.1:8072;
    }



# http -> https
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name odoo.mycompany.com; #replace with your domain
   rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
 listen 443;
 server_name odoo.mycompany.com; #replace with your domain
 proxy_read_timeout 720s;
 proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
 proxy_send_timeout 720s;

 # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

 # SSL parameters - update with your cert details
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;
 ssl_session_timeout 30m;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 # log
 access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

 # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
 location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://odoo;
 }
 location /longpolling {
     proxy_pass http://odoochat;
 }

 # common gzip
 gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
 gzip on;
}
```

As you can see there is also upstream for the chat as it works on the other port.
Remember to create a shortcut in the sites-enabled:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoursite.com
```

Later on test nginx config and restart it:

```
nginx -t
service nginx restart
```

Mentioned config comes from:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/deploy.html

4) Update your Odoo config with:
- proxy_mode = True
- workers = you need to have more than one worker if you want the "chat" and "discuss" modules to work properly.

Comment: will this expire after one year? If yes how to renew certificate?

Comment: you can setup certbot to auto-renew. I am using it on my Odoo website(www.cier.tech) and will make a tutorial when will have some spare time;)